# Непонятные запросы к сайту

Tags: html

Здравствуйте! В логе обнаружил сегодня тонну таких запросов: "217.167.141.219 <URL моего сайта> - - [01/Apr/2013:14:59:28 +0400] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 216 "-" "VbwOGxeV bfuTOj2e" 3572 0" Все с одного IP адреса. Что это такое, подбор паролей брутфорсом? У меня CMS Joomla. Я забанил конечно IP этот в .htaccess, теперь в логе 403 вместо 200. Запросы идут до сих пор. Что делать?

Comment: можно заблочить на уровне iptables, разгрузит веб-сервер. а что ещё тут сделаешь? в полицию звонить? ))

Comment: Да он несильно грузит то, раз в минуту два запроса GET и POST такого вида. Просто хотел понять что это такое? Это бот? Почему вместо Агента билиберда какая то?

Comment: Ну забаните вы одного, а к вам еще 1000 придет, это вам надо что б сидел человек и отлавливал каждого засранца, и в итоге соберете список ботов со всего миру. А по факту, забить, ну или кабель выдернуть.)

Comment: так.. @Alex не слушай его ))) попробуй fail2ban - можно использовать для автоматического блокирования по неудачным попыткам логина. Всё есть в гугле с примерами.

Comment: кхм, а где вы тут увидели попытки логина? Тут просто GET запрос.

Comment: ну.. если там попыткой сделать GET /administrator/ игнорируется robots.txt, то я б заблочил

Comment: Честно, я вам не советую так делать. В кратце объясню почему, я зашел к вам на  GET /administrator/ , вы меня в бан, я такой "угу", я вам на генерирую 1000^10 запросов с разных ip и все их вы положите в бан, который не резиновый. И есть вероятность что тем самым я произведу отказ в обслуживание.

Comment: @pyatak и много у тебя адресов в разных подсетях? при каком-то аврале я блочу подсеть.. но конечно вручную пока, но у меня есть точная логика, которую можно делать.

Comment: Не подумай, в твоих действиях есть доля правды, главное без паранои.Просто забавно видеть, когда у людей, причем у серьезных людей, висит такой блэк лист, что его по гигабитному каналу целый день тащить, а ведь если задуматься, закрывают то что, а закрывают дыры в софте, закрывают дыры в паролях "123", получается что лечат симптомы а не саму болезнь, вот я к чему.

Answer (score 2):

Если идут постоянные post-запросы именно к /administrator/, то скорее всего это попытка подобрать пароль либо же попытка использовать какую-то уязвимость. Иначе ботам там нечего делать. А чтобы не заниматься ерундой с забаниванием айпишников, рекомендуется разместить админку по адресу, который будет неизвестен ботам, хотя бы /adminka123454321/.